# Implementing action on moveUp in NSTextField

Tags: xcode, keypress, nstextfield

So I've just started with some mac developing. My first project is to develop a text based calculator which only consist of two components, one NSTextField and one NSTextView. The TextField takes user input and display the answer in the TextView. What I would like is to implement a function where if the TextField is active and the up arrow is pressed the input goes through the command history. I know how to implement the history function but not how to capture the keypress. I've searched and found in [Capturing "up" and "down" keys pressed in NSTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648183/capturing-up-and-down-keys-pressed-in-nstextfield)  that one way is to implement:

`- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)fieldEditor
       doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector {`

The problem is that since I'm quite new to mac development I still don't get how to implement the function?

Comment: This is a delegate function of textview.You have to create a property of the text field in the class

Comment: The accepted answer of the other question that you link to shows how to implement that method.  What exactly is giving you difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface AppDelgate <NSTextViewDelegate>

@property IBOutlet (nonatomic,strong) NSTextView* myTextView;

@end

@implementation

-(BOOL) applicationDidLaunch(..) {
  myTextView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
//check theEvent.keyCode (125=up arrow)
}

@end
```

Comment: Can't get the keyUp function to be called.
My NSTextField is called inputString and it has a "Referencing outlet" as App Delegate. Is this correct?
Does this mean  I don't have to set "inputString.delegate = self" because xcode complains and says it should be "_input...." but if i change the application does not launch.

Comment: 1) correctly 2) No, it has to be `self.inputString.delegate = self` as  inputString is a property of AppDelegate.